# CakePHP - Validate a field using values from an other model

Tags: validation, cakephp, model, field

I wonder if it's possible to validate a field with a method like `inList()` but using values from an other field in an other model:

For example I want to validate `type_id` field of the `Member` model using values from `id` field from `MemberType` model.
**`Member`** model

```
<?php

class Member extends AppModel
{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        "MemberType" => array(
            "className" => "MemberType"
        )
    );

    public $validate = array(
        "type_id" => array(
            "validType" => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('A', 'B')),
                'message' => 'Choose an existing type'
            )
        )
    );

}
```

**`MemberType`** model

```
<?php

class MemberType extends AppModel
{

}
```

Comment: No I don't think so. At least for version 2.x. You have to create your custom validation rule in order to do that. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Thanks, that's the only alternative solution I've find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to validate `type_id` field using a custom validation method :

```
<?php

class Member extends AppModel
{

    public $belongsTo = array(
        "MemberType" => array(
            "className" => "MemberType"
        )
    );

    public $validate = array(
        "type_id" => array(
            "validType" => array(
                'rule' => array('validMemberType'),
                'message' => 'Choose an existing type'
            )
        )
    );

    public function validMemberType($check){
        $types = array_keys($this->MemberType->find("list"));
        return in_array($check["type_id"], $types);
    }
}
```